# Can I use 'eval' to define a function in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, eval

I want to define a Python function using eval:

```
func_obj = eval('def foo(a, b):  return a + b')
```

But it return invalid syntax error?
How can I make it?

Btw, how can I transform a function obj to a string object in Python?

Comment: why do you need eval()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Answer (score 28):

Use `exec`. `eval` is used for expressions not statements.

```
>>> exec 'def foo(a, b):  return a + b'
>>> foo(1, 2)
3
```

Function code from function object:

```
def func():
    """ I'm func """
    return "Hello, World"
... 
>>> import inspect
>>> print inspect.getsource(func)
def func():
    """ I'm func """
    return "Hello, World"
```

Comment: how can I convert a function object to string?

Comment: @xunzhang It is possible only if function is defined somewhere, use `inspect.getsource`.

Comment: see this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740380/how-to-invoke-clients-callback-at-server-end), that is what I really need~

Comment: @xunzhang Please ask only one question at a time.

Comment: Downvoted as your answer does not include why this is a bad idea and should not be done - and in OPs case, as mentioned by his previous comment, probably all he needs is `getattr`.

Comment: @hcwhsa thanks for your answer. But I do not think half solving problem or not solving a real problem is good, at least for myself.

Comment: Upvoted because it is clear with good examples, and doesn’t bother with explaining why this is a bad thing because that is all over the internet, and we should assume intelligence on the part of readers of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `eval` with `lambda`, like:

```
func_obj = lambda a, b: eval('a + b')
```

Comment: ```def f(a,b) = return eval('a+b')``` does the same.

Answer (score 4):

```
def test_eval():
    exec('def foo(a, b):  return a + b')   
    foo(1, 2)
```

@niitsuma This code will return error: `NameError: name 'foo' is not defined`

This is because foo is defined in other scope that you execute it. To fix it and make it visible in oouter scope, you can make foo global variable:

```
def test_eval():
    exec('global foo\ndef foo(a, b):  return a + b')   
    foo(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote

```py
def test_eval():
    exec('def foo(a, b):  return a + b')   
    foo(1, 2)
```

in `mypackage/tests/test_mycode.py` with approprite `mypackage/setup.py`.
But `python setup.py test` cause 
`NameError: name 'foo' is not defined`.

How to test codes from string?